# not understanding 'No overload matches this call' error

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have been making an weather app following Angular for Enterprise-Ready Web Applications - Second Edition book and am implementing the search component for the app to display weather by the searched city. But, am getting above mentioned error on 'city-search' component.ts file.
full error is :

> No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 2, '(observerOrNext?: Partial<Observer<string | null>> | ((value: string | null) => void) | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '(searchValue: string) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<Observer<string | null>> | ((value: string | null) => void) | undefined'.
> Type '(searchValue: string) => void' is not assignable to type '(value: string | null) => void'.
> Types of parameters 'searchValue' and 'value' are incompatible.
> Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
> Overload 2 of 2, '(next?: ((value: string | null) => void) | null | undefined, error?: ((error: any) => void) | null | undefined, complete?: (() => void) | null | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.

*city-search.component.ts:*

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { WeatherService } from '../weather/weather.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-city-search',
  templateUrl: './city-search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./city-search.component.css']
})
export class CitySearchComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() searchEvent = new EventEmitter<string>()
  search = new FormControl('', [Validators.minLength(2)])

  constructor(private weatherService: WeatherService){}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.search.valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(1000)).subscribe((searchValue: string) => {
      if (!this.search.invalid) {
        this.searchEvent.emit(searchValue)
        const userInput = searchValue.split(',').map(s => s.trim())
      this.weatherService.getCurrentWeather(
        userInput[0],
        userInput.length > 1 ? userInput[1] : undefined
      ).subscribe(data => (console.log(data)))
    }
  })
}
}
```

I am providing the git link you can find the project there: https://github.com/soorajKADAM/local-weather-app.git

I did not understand what the error means,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error tells you that there is a type mismatch. When tracing down the error, you can see that the `valueChanges` Observable is defined to push values of the shape `string | null`. This is because by default, a reactive form control is nullable, see the [docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#description). However, in your code you only expect a `searchValue` of type `string`, you don't handle the possibility of it being null.

There are two possibilities to fix it:

### Add `null` to type definition

The first solution is to extend the type of `searchValue` to also allow `null`. To properly handle the `null` case, I added a check to the existing `if` statement. Updated code:

```
this.search.valueChanges
  .pipe(debounceTime(1000))
  .subscribe((searchValue: string | null) => {
    if (searchValue !== null && !this.search.invalid) {
      // further code...
    }
  });
```

### Define the form control as non-nullable

In case your form control should not be nullable, you can define it as such like the following:

```
search = new FormControl('', {
  nonNullable: true,
  validators: [Validators.minLength(2)]
});
```